# SendKeys to dialogbox is not working for Siebel

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, siebel

Hi I am using the below code to insert data in windows dialog of Siebel. Its not entering .Please help me with it.
Thanks

```
String text="abc";
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alertText = alert.getText();
alertText=driver.switchTo().alert().getText();
alert.sendKeys(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String text="abc";
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
String alertMessage = driver.switchTo().alert().getText();
driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys(text);
```

Comment: Is there any way I can reproduce this in my system?

Comment: Hi ,
The issue is resolved . sendKeys() is working . But in Chrome new value entered in dialog was not displayed, but it was entering new value. After accepting dialog . New value was present in textfield.Thanks for looking into the isse.